# Python (Pillow): 'str' has no attribute 'read'. Using Pillow to read and display an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've been given an example program to read a .pgm file and display it as an image:

```
from scipy import misc      # Import misc 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
#         Get the filename as string
fn = str(raw_input("filename.pgm"))

#         Read file it np array
im = misc.imread(fn)


#         Display with grayscale colour map 
plt.imshow(im,cmap=plt.cm.gray)

#         Show the image
plt.show()

main()
```

the problem is that when I run the program, I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ImageTest.py", line 18, in <module>
 main()
File "ImageTest.py", line 9, in main
 im = misc.imread(fn)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\utils.py", line 101, in newfunc
 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py", line 164, in imread
 im = Image.open(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2536, in open
 fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is there something I'm missing, or is there an error in the example code?

Comment: First, `imread` is deprecated, so you should use `imageio.imread` instead (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html). Also, it looks like for some reason the version you're using expects an actual file pointer instead of just the filename, so you probably have to do something like `fp = open("filename.pmg")` then `misc.imread(fp)`

Comment: Thanks. But if I use the open("filename.pmg") line, I get an error about it being a float.

Comment: Did you try opening it in binary format? `open("filename.pmg", "rb")`